# Pass arguments to the script via pm2 programmatically (API)

Tags: node.js, pm2

I try to pass arguments to my script by using PM2 programmatically

```js
pm2.start('./MyScript.js', {
  name: MyScript,
  script: './MyScript.js',
  exec_mode : "cluster",
  instances: 1,
  args : '-- MyArg1 MyArg2',
  }, function(err, apps) {
  pm2.disconnect();
  if (err) throw err
});
```

In 'MyScript1' I'm just printing the command line arguments

```js
console.log('Script started with process.argv  \'' + process.argv + '\'');
return(0);
```

The result is always

```
Script started with process.argv  'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe,C:\Workspace\..\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainer.js'
```

I get the same result if I use '--node-args'

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have checked the implementation of `API.js`. Instead `args` you have to use the property `scriptArgs`